# Wrong dividing in python

Tags: python, python-2.x

As you can see from watch, `l[u][0]` must be `0.5`, but it returns `0`

```
u = 0
for j in range(n):
    if k == j:
        continue
    l[u][0] = -x[j] / (x[k] - x[j])
    l[u][1] = 1 / (x[k] - x[j])
    u = u + 1
```

[image: screenshot]

What's wrong with it?

Comment: Integer division. ALso, please take the time to type (or copy) that code into your question, instead of linking some image with the code inside.

Comment: Worth noting that, on python3 however `1/2` gives `0.5` by default without explicit casting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The division is not "wrong". It is integer division (a.k.a. floor division).

When you divide two integers, the result is an integer:

```
>>> 3/4
0
>>> 4/4
1
```

When you divide two floating-point numbers (numbers with a fractional part), the result is a float:

```
>>> 3./4
0.75
>>> 4./4
1.0
```

Note that this "problem" is confined to Python 2. One of the changes in Python 3 is to make normal division coerce to floats:

```
>>> 3/4   # Python 3 behavior
0.75
```

and to require a second operator (also in Python >2.2) to achieve integer division:

```
>>> 3//4
0
```

Comment: `from __future__ import division` will enable the new behaviour in 2.2+ too.

Comment: @ChrisWesseling Good point. Should have mentioned that!